# Angle that a point clicked makes with vertical

Tags: android

I need to create analog clock in which hours is displayed at centre and minutes on circumference of circle.I need to calculate angle that the point on circumference where user clicks, makes with vertical to calculate minutes.Any help would be useful..

Answer (score 0):

The formula would be

```
angle/totalDegrees * 60
```

Depending on how you've got your angle defined ofcourse, but lets default to 'normal' degrees: 
you've got 60 minutes and 360 degrees.

straight down, aka 180 degrees, would be 30 minutes. STraight up would be 0 minutes and 0 degrees, etc.

That would make your calculation

```
angle/360 * 60
```

You would have the mapping

```
180 -> 30
  0 ->  0
 90 -> 15
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need help on how to get that angle on click of image(not how to calculate minutes).

Comment: Could you update your question and make it a bit clearer then? Maybe even give some more info like what you have, etc etc.

Comment: When i click anywhere on circumference of circle,i need to calculate appropriate minutes it points to.What you have said is a step ahead.Before that how do i capture that point and calculate angle ?

Answer (score 0):

This gives the standard angle, positive x-as has angle of zero:

```
angle = Math.atan2(clicky-clockCenterY,clickx-clockCenterX)
```

To make 12 o'clock (angle of [pi/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)) the zero angle, just subtract pi/2:

```
angle = Math.atan2(clicky-clockCenterY,clickx-clockCenterX) - Math.Pi/2.0;
```

Javadoc for [Math.atan2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29)

The given angle is in radians (2pi for a full circle), to convert this to minutes (60 for a full circle):

```
minuteAngle = 60.0*(angle / (2.0*Math.Pi))
```

This might give a value of -15minutes, what should be 45 minutes so:

```
if (minuteAngle < 0.0)
  minuteAngle += 60.0;
```